# Formalizing the Askar'yan Effect

Tags: electromagnetism, particle-physics, experimental-physics, elementary-particles, cherenkov-radiation

Wikipedia defines the [Askar'yan Effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gurgen_Askaryan#Askaryan_effect) as...

> [The] Askaryan effect is the phenomenon whereby a particle traveling faster than the phase velocity of light in a dense dielectric... produces a shower of secondary charged particles which contain a charge anisotropy and thus emits a cone of coherent radiation in the radio or microwave part of the electromagnetic spectrum.

---

**What I know...**

The Akar'yan effect is typically discussed in the context of *neutrinos*. As I understand it, the process works something like this:

A neutrino, traveling faster than the phase velocity of light in some dielectric media (e.g. ice) disrupts the local electromagnetic field of the medium. Electrons in the medium are displaced and polarized by the passing electromagnetic field. Photons are emitted as the electrons restore themselves to equilibrium. Under normal circumstances, the photons destructively interfere and no net radiation is detectable. In the Askar'yan effect, the neutrino's moving faster than the local speed of light leads to a constructive interference, which in turn leads to detectable radiation.

On a "macroscopic" scale, a shower of secondary charged particles, which contain a charge anisotropy, is emitted. Somehow, the phases of the emitted photons are *identical* and, as a result, the net "detectable" radiation scales quadratically with the shower energy.

---

**What I don't understand...**

I know what each of these pieces mean, for the large part, and I believe to understand the subject on a broad scale, however there are a few dots I'm struggling to connect and, more so, I'm interested in *formalizing* this a bit more. Sadly, there isn't much literature on the topic out there that isn't either somewhat "broad", such as this overview, or very technical.

Firstly, I don't understand how the neutrino could possibly interact with the electromagnetic field of some medium. The neutrino is *not* a charged particle. Further, how, precisely, does the neutrino's moving faster than the "local" speed of light in some medium lead to a constructive interference? Lastly,  how is it that the phases of the emitted photons end up being precisely identical?

I'm looking for a more formal treatment of the subject.

Comment: Neutrinos would not interact with the electromagnetic field. They interact extremely rarely, but there are a lot of them. When they do interact it is via the weak force. They typically convert a neutron to a proton and electron (I am not sure of details). The electron would likely be the particle that generate radiation. Neutrinos can fly through the earth without interacting. But if they interact near the surface, radiation might escape and be detected.

Comment: Maybe the introduction and references  of this paper will help you. https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-ex/0611008.pdf  . a new method which we denote the ra-dio Cherenkov technique, has emerged within the last decade.This  method  relies  on  properties  of  electromagnetic  cas-cades  in  a  dielectric  medium.   It  was  first  hypothesized byAskaryan [4] and confirmed in 2001 at SLAC  [5]  ....

Comment: It is a secondary effect of cerenkov cascades, as far as i see, not direct neutrino interactions with medium